# imprimir en impreso de punto o de recibos desde jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hola tengo un formulario en jsp y quiero imprimirlo en una impreso de punto, me explico una impresora de recibos, debo agregar alguna librería o como lo podría hacer?

esta es la jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ingreso
    Created on : 20/07/2016, 12:59:42 PM
    Author     : jefma
--%>


<%@page import="Controlador.NumRecibo"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="resource/img/index.ico"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>Generar Recibo</title>
        <link href="resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="resource/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="resource/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resource/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="resource/js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container">
            <div  class="page-header page-header2 text-left">
                <img src="resource/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive " alt="Responsive image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                <div class="text-right col-md-7 ">
                    <h3 class="media-heading colorsub"><b>Generar Ingreso</b> </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right col-md-5 ">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-defaul btn-primary2 " type="button" onclick="history.back()">Regresar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style = "margin-top:120px">

                <form action="IngresaMateria" method="post" class="form" id="ingresom">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label  ">Recibo Numero:</label>         
                            <input type="inputtext" class="form-control" id="nit" name="numrecibo" placeholder="NIT" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style = "margin-top:20px">
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label ">Razon social:</label>
                            <select  id="nomFuent" name="nomFuent" class="form-control"required >
                                <option> </option>  
                                <%
                                    List<NumRecibo> lista = (List<NumRecibo>) request.getAttribute("listado");

                                    int i = 0;
                                    for (NumRecibo numRecibo : lista) {

                                        String nombrefuente = (numRecibo.getNombre());
                                        out.println("<option value=" + nombrefuente + ">" + nombrefuente + "</option>");
                                    }

                                %>


                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label  ">Nit Fuente:</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="i_opc" id="i_opc">
                            <select id="nitfuentes" name="nitfuente" class="form-control"required >
                                <option value="">seleccione</option>
                            </select>

                            <% for (NumRecibo numRecibo : lista) {
                                    i++;
                                    int t = lista.size();

                                    if (i == t) {
                                        String nitA = (numRecibo.getNitAsociado());
                                        String nom = (numRecibo.getNomAsociado());
                            %>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label  ">Nit Asociado:</label>         

                            <input type="inputtext" class="form-control" id="nit" name="nitSocio" placeholder="NIT" value="<%=nitA%>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label ">Nombre Asociado:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Razonsocial" name="nomSocio" placeholder="Razon social" value="<%=nom%>">
                        </div><%}
                            }%>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12" style = "margin-top:20px">

                        <table id="tablaMateriales" class="table table-bordered" >


                            <thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">No</th>

                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col ">Clase Residuo</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Tipo Residuo</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Cantida Kilos</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Unitario</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Total</th>


                                    <th colspan="2" scope="col">Rechazo</th>
                                </tr>

                                <tr> 
                                    <th scope="col"  >Kilos</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Valor</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-sm-1 ">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-2 "><select id="tipomaterial" name="tipomaterial" class="form-control " required="">
                                            <option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
                                            <option value="Metales" >Metales </option>
                                            <option value="Papel-Carton" >Papel-Carton</option>
                                            <option value="Plasticos" >Plasticos</option>
                                            <option value="Vidrio" >Vidrio</option>
                                            <option value="Reuso" >Reuso</option>

                                        </select></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-2 "><select id="tiporesiduo" name="tiporesiduo" class="form-control ">

                                        </select></td></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" id="txtCantidadKilos"  pattern="[0-9]" name="kilos" maxlength="6" type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" id="txtValorUnitario" name="ValorUnitario" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-2 "><input type="text" id="txtValorTotal" name="ValorTotal"class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" id="txtKilosRechazo" name="KilosRechazo" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-2 "><input type="text" id="txtValorRechazo" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td class="text-center">

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>    
                        </table>
                        <input id="hiddenValorTotal" name="valortotal"type="hidden" value="0" />
                        <input id="hiddenSubtotal" name="valorSubtotal"type="hidden" value="0" />
                        <input id="hiddenTotalRechazo" type="hidden" value="0" />
                        <input id="tabla" name="tabla" type="hidden" value="" />
                        <table id ="gridMateriales" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover"  > 
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Remove</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">No</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Clase Residuo</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Tipo Residuo</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Cantida Kilos</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Unitario</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Total</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" scope="col">Rechazo</th>

                                </tr>

                                <tr> 
                                    <th scope="col"  >Kilos</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>

                        <table id ="tablatotales" class="table table-bordered table-responsive " >   

                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-5">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                    Sub Total 
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                                    <span id="granSubtotal"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-5">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                    IVA 
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td  class="col-sm-1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-5">
                                </td>
                                <td  class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                    Total 
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                                    <span id="granTotal"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div  class= "tamanobotton btn btn-primary btn-defaul" id="btnnuevo">Nuevo</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 "style = "margin-top:40px">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-defaul btn-primary2 pull-right " name="Ingresar" type="submit" >Ingresar</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
                        <div  class="page-header text-center page-header2">
                            <img src="resource/img/logo2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


            </div>
        </form>
</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Puedes usar Jasper, puedes encontrar toda la información aquí: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library